# importing global.d.ts without triple-slash directives

Tags: typescript, es6-modules, .d.ts

**Context**: trying to get mocha to run tests on .ts files in my repo.

**Problem**: when I try running mocha on my entry-tests file:

```
mocha --compilers ts:ts-node/register ./src/server/backend/specs/index.spec.ts
```

I discover that `ts-node` won't see `"include": ["./src/**/*"]` within my `tsconfig.json` file (according to [ts-node's documentation](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node)). That means my mocha tests don't see `./src/types/global.d.ts`, which includes the definition of `type Omit<T, K>` (amongst other things). My tested modules want to make use of `Omit`, which leads to a compiler error `Cannot find name 'Omit'`.

Fine -- I think to myself -- I'll just import `global.d.ts` into `index.spec.ts` using a triple-slash directive. So added `/// <reference path="../../../types/global.d.ts" />` to the top of `index.spec.ts` and got this complaint from ts-lint: `<reference> is not allowed, use imports (no-reference)`. (News to me -- triple-slash directives are [now deprecated](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-reference/), and we're advised to "use ES6-style imports instead".)

OK, so I naively, replace the triple-slash directive with `import "../../../types/global";` but then tsc complains of course that `global.d.ts` is not a module (which of course it is not). Indeed, I use `global.d.ts` to declare things that aren't modules, so I'm confused how you are supposed to import it -- and I dont want to export anything from `global.d.ts` because my understanding is that it will then cease to produce its global readability in the main-non-mocha context.

It works fine when I just use the triple-slash directive with the no-reference rule switched off in ts-lint, but I'd like to understand better what the latest patterns/thinking is here. Thanks anyone!

Comment: Hi, facing the same today. Was wondering if you found a good solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Google [finds](https://www.google.com/search?q=tslint+%22no-reference%22) [an issue about this](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/1562), where the recommendation was to add the global declaration file directly to your project in `tsconfig.json`.  In the case of ts-node, you'd have to use the `--files` option.  If you don't want to do that, there isn't a good alternative, so I'd say suppressing the lint warning or disabling the `no-reference` rule is the right thing to do.  You could consider opening a new issue against tslint to discuss this scenario further.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Just wanted to confirm there isn't a more-modern approach. I'll just suppress for now with a note to check on this in the future.